# How to get server info from user input | discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Objective: Trying to obtain guild information from user input (text)

Code:

```
    if (message.content.startsWith(prefix)){
        const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
        const argsresult = args.join(" ");
        const guilds = client.guilds.fetch(argsresult)
        message.channel.send(`Server ID: ${guilds.then(guild => guild.id)} \n Server Name: ${guilds.then(guild => guild.name)}`)
    }
```

Result:

[image]

Issue: It's not printing the string that it should be printing

Second Code Attempt:

```
    if (message.content.startsWith(prefix)){
        const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
        const argsresult = args.join(" ");
        const guilds = client.guilds.fetch(argsresult)
        const guildsID = guilds.then(guild => guild.id)
        const guildsName = guilds.then(guild => guild.name)
        message.channel.send(`Server ID: ${guildsID} \n Server Name: ${guildsName}`)
    }
```

Result: The same as before

**How do I obtain the guild info just from ID that the user has inputed???**

Comment: You should await the promise before outputting any data.

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to the `guilds` variable returns a promise. Check the code below:

```
 if (message.content.startsWith(prefix)){
        const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
        const argsresult = args.join(" ");
        const guilds = client.guilds.fetch(argsresult)
        guilds.then(guild => {
            message.channel.send(`Server ID: ${guild.id} \n Server Name: ${guid.name}`)
        })
    }
```